# Mesuring Derby speed with hibernate. Strange values

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing application to mesure speed of CRUD with hibernate for Derby.

This is my function :

```
  @Override
    public BulkTestResult testBulkInsertScenario(Long volume, Integer repeat) {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        BulkTestResult bulkTestResult = new BulkTestResult();
        bulkTestResult.setStartDate(Instant.now());
        bulkTestResult.setCountTest(volume);
        bulkTestResult.setTestRepeat(repeat);
        familyService.clear();
       for(int i =0; i < repeat; i++) {
           List<ProjectEntity> projects = dataAnonymization.generateProjectEntityList(volume);
           runBulkTest(sw, bulkTestResult, projects, true);
       }

        bulkTestResult.setEndDate(Instant.now());
        return bulkTestResult;
    }

    private void runBulkTest(StopWatch sw, BulkTestResult bulkTestResult, List<ProjectEntity> projects, boolean resetAfter) {
        sw.reset();
        sw.start();
        familyService.save(projects);
        sw.stop();
        bulkTestResult.addMsSpeedResult(sw.getTime());
        if (resetAfter) familyService.clear();
        sw.reset();
    }
```

clear method remove all record from DB.

The problem that I have is values that I recieved as output of application.
Testing data : 1000 record, and 10 repeats

Example speed values recieved running this test few times:

> 1. 311, 116, 87, (...)38
> 2. 32, 27, 30, (...) 24
> 3. 22, 19, 18, (...) 21
> 4. 19, 18, 18, (...) 19

Why there are so many difference and why for first time insert is always slower ? 
It could be any hardware acceleration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. 
This issue is related to optimalization. After Disable JIT, recieved values are correct.

-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xint